# Is there path lifting from the circle to the long line?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces

I understand that the long line isn't a covering space for $S^1$, as has been discussed in other places, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42844/why-is-the-long-line-not-a-covering-space-for-the-circle).

However, does the projection map to $S^1$ satisfy path lifting? Intuitively it seems so?
If so, how does that relate to the result that path lifting + a local homeomorphism implies a covering map (Theorem 4.19 from [here](https://staff.math.su.se/shapiro/UIUC/Foster.pdf))?

I should say, I am not well-versed with dealing with ordinals, and am trying to self learn covering spaces etc.

Comment: As mentioned in your first link, a map that wraps each segment of the long line around the circle is not continuous at the limit ordinals. Is this discontinuous function your "projection map"?

Comment: The map that is discussed in your link isn't well-defined at limit ordinals.

Comment: I guess I was thinking that the long line, defined as $\omega\times[0,1)$ could be mapped to $[0,1)$ through a projection map without any issues. And that could be mapped to $S^1$. Maybe I misunderstood what was being claimed in the answer to the first link I put above. Is the projection map to [0,1) itself not well defined somehow? I should say, I am not well-versed with dealing with ordinals, and am trying to self learn covering spaces etc.

Comment: @SarthakC The issue with that is that the long line is $\omega\times[0,1)$ equipped with the order topology, not the product topology.

Comment: @Thorgott: Ah, that's what I was missing. If one does consider the product topology on the long line, then I imagine path lifting holds and it is a covering map?

Comment: No, lifting to a product is a component-wise question and the map $[0,1)\rightarrow S^1$ does not satisfy path-lifting.

Comment: Yeah, okay, that makes sense, thanks.